# Did Melody actually fall through the door?

Tags: plot-explanation, griff-the-invisible

In the movie "Griff the Invisible" does Melody actually fall through the door, or have they both gone 'around the bend'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The title actor, Ryan Kwanten was keen to emphasise in this [Collider interview](http://collider.com/ryan-kwanten-griff-the-invisible-interview/) that Griff isn't mentally unstable. It follows that a bit of stress and grief would hardly be likely to lead to a psychotic break or freeform hallucinations:

> Q. ***Did you approach him as somebody who is delusional, or did you approach him more as somebody who’s developed this little world to
>   deal with how everybody treats him?***
>
> **KWANTEN:** *The latter, definitely. **I didn’t see him with any kind of mental disorder, at all. Maybe he has a little bit of socio-phobia,
>   but outside of that, it’s more just someone who had chosen to embrace
>   his imagination, and that just evolved over time.***

In [this interview with Quickflix](https://www.quickflix.co.nz/News/Interviews/GrifftheInvisible/7342), the Director (Leon Ford) seems to strongly concur:

> **SM:** *And a few years later, you starred as Hamlet on stage, and he
>   certainly has his psychological issues that he’s working through.
>   Griff is not at these extremes, but he’s suffering from his own
>   delusions. I’m interested in what fascinates you about these types of
>   characters.*
>
> **LF:** *Well, I just don’t think they’re that far from any of us. Paranoid
>   schizophrenia is probably one of the most tragic diseases you can
>   have, and not something I’d wish on anyone. **The sort-of lesser
>   extremes – delusions, whether by choice or involuntary – the playful
>   side of us is suppressed too much or hidden away. We’ve all got
>   something inside of us that is playful that we suppress because it’s
>   considered immature or silly. We get used to conforming and appearing
>   we’re all normal, but I don’t think anyone is. I think everyone is an
>   eccentric, and I hope a film like Griff celebrates that, rather than
>   makes people feel ashamed of it.** Obviously there is a dark side to the
>   spectrum and a light side; and I seem to get a lot of those characters
>   [like Hamlet] but I think there’s nothing wrong with it*

The implication is that Griff is **fully capable of distinguishing his fantasies from genuine reality** and therefore **what he sees at the end of the film is the literal truth**. She did indeed fall through the door.